# Why doesn't any object prototype work as a forEach callback?

Tags: javascript, prototype, declarative-programming

Rather than a question, I just wanted it to be a challenge but couldn't find an answer yet.

For example, we have an array of strings

```
x = ['a', '   b', '  c  ']
```

and I want to trim all the elements. I tried `apply` and `call` methods but neither worked as expected:

```
x.forEach(String.prototype.trim.call)
// Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

x.forEach(String.prototype.trim.apply)
// Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and not a function
```

What's going on here? `apply`/`call` should take their first argument from for each function and everything seems fine.

Comment: This is a good case for a class static method: `String.trim = function(s) { return s.trim() }; x = x.map(String.trim)`

Comment: @thefourtheye: Why do you think that it's a duplicate?

Comment: @Guffa it clearly is a dupe.  Unfortunately the spec for `.map` and `.forEach` didn't allow for the current element to be passed as `this`, unlike the jQuery equivalents.

Comment: @Guffa as op I confirm this is a duplicate. See comments in accepted answers. Author asked the same as I asked.

Comment: Ok, I didn't follow it that deep. I only reacted to the fact that it's clearly not a duplicate of the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.call()` will call the function stored in `foo`.

i.e. the value of `this` inside `call` will be `foo`.

The function you pass to `forEach` gets called without explicit context, so the value of `this` will be the default object (`window` in a browser).

`window` is not a function, so it errors.

You can use `bind` to create a new function that calls a function with a specific context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
x = ['a', '   b', '  c  ']
x.map(function(item) { return item.trim() })
```