# javascript: Why can some functions be bound and mapped and others not?

Tags: javascript

Out of curiosity:

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Creating_shortcuts) taught me how to shortcut function application like this:

```
trim = Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.trim)

join = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.join)
```

Now, I can map `trim`, but not `join` for some reason. `join` takes `','` as default argument (separator), so I should be fine, but instead it uses the array index:

```
> trim = Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.trim)
call()
> [' a','b '].map(trim)
["a", "b"]
> join = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.join)
call()
> [['a','b'],['c','d']].map(join)
["a0b", "c1d"]
```

Why?

Also, what if I actually wanted a different separator? Passing it to `bind` doesn't work, since it is prepended to the existing arguments (at any time one of the elements of the list on which I map). Then it takes the role of the strings to join and the strings to join would act as separators if there was something to separate:

```
> joins = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.join,';')
call()
> [['a','b'],['c','d']].map(joins)
[";", ";"]
```

I have researched and found:

[Answers explaining the thing with `this` and solutions equivalent to the `bind` shortcut I referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280974/why-doesnt-a-b-c-mapstring-prototype-tolowercase-call-work)

[Similar explanations, the solution using `thisArg` again, from MDN's page about `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304007/why-wont-passing-trim-straight-to-maps-callback-work)

[A duplicate question with duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940461/why-doesnt-any-object-prototype-work-as-a-foreach-callback)

Comment: This answers the "Why?": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Example:_Tricky_use_case

Comment: Well, `trim` does ignore the arguments it's passed, `join` *doesn't*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you pass into map receives 3 arguments. Basically map works like this.

```
Array.prototype.map = function(f) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    result.push(f(this[i], i, this));
  }
  return result;
}
```

So when you run this code
`[['a','b'],['c','d']].map(join)`,
this is what's happening inside `map`

```
join(['a', 'b'], 0, [['a','b'],['c','d']])
join(['c', 'd'], 1, [['a','b'],['c','d']])
```

To get the result you want you could write a function that can generate join functions. e.g.

```
function joinSep(separator) {
  return function(array) {
    return array.join(separator)
  }
}
var joins = joinSep(';');
[['a','b'],['c','d']].map(joins)
```